# How can I bring low voltage wire through foundation

Tags: wiring, foundation

My house currently has a wiring situation that has caused a leak and water damage. See the attached picture for locations.

I have a sprinkler timer in the utility room inside the house. The wires for the sprinkler valves in the backyard present no problem. The old valves in the front of the house, however go through a hole drilled through the foundation below grade and it looks like filled with caulk.

Low voltage wiring for the landscape lighting also goes through that same hole, and back out the back of the house in the utility room.

I hadn't thought much about this setup since I bought the house until we found water damage last week. Now I want to fix this situation the right way.

There is no electrical box on the front or sides of the house for a sprinkler timer or transformer. The wires have to get to the back of the house. Unfortunately the house is surrounded by concrete. I think this is why they decided going through the house is the best option.

What would be the best (including cost and ease) and right way to get those wires to where they need to go? Above grade conduit that's sealed? Tunneling under all the concrete? The width of the house is about 60 feet wide and the drawing is roughly to scale so that would be a lot of concrete to tunnel under.

[image: Rough plot layout]

Comment: Could you go into the house above the foundation into the floor joist cavity? Run your wires into the basement and along the ceiling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I intend to do is pull the wires through the hole and patch it using hydraulic cement.

I will then drill a new hole above grade around the corner out of site. I will feed conduit through, to an IB fitting, then in conduit down underground. The hole/conduit will be sealed with caulk.

I've been waiting for the winter to end before I fix this.